# How do you call these classes?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a collective name for these non-"helper" classes which encapsulate method results (e.g. "SignupResult"), classes which hold multiple filter values (e.g. "ContactSearchFilter"), my SortDirection enum etc.  -- I want to organize these correctly but can't find the correct name for these as a whole. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do they really have anything in common that would justify an own category name?

If you want to organize such files, I suggest putting them in the same folder/namespace as their dependencies, i.e. the `enum` belongs in the same namespace as the dictionary you use it with, `SignupResult` belongs together with the other signup process classes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you do with it. If you save it in the database, it's effectively an 'Entity'. If you just use it to pass variables around, I'd call it a 'Holder' class (though that's not really a formal term).

It's arguably interesting to consider that if you have too many of these, perhaps your design is not so great. You probably shouldn't be so-much passing results around, as doing actions based on things happening. JMHO. FWIW.

Comment: No these are not entities or domain related. Yes, looking for a better term than 'holder' class....

Comment: I normally use an struct, if I'm just passing around pointers to things. But like I'm hinting at, I rarely have these things. Then generally end up as their own fully-fledged, and deserving, classes, inside a 'core' lib structure, or are just not required.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps creating a class called UserSession or something and have things like SignupResult/ContactSearchFilter as properties.